# E-cigarette accidents

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a data set that contains e-cigarette accidents where e-cigs have exploded and damage someone around (e.g., the vapers), with as many following fields as possible:

- timestamp
- geolocation
- casualties and nature of casualties
- model of e-cig

Answer (score 4):

There are 4 incidents from 2015 in [NEISS](https://www.cpsc.gov/en/Research--Statistics/NEISS-Injury-Data/) (National Electronic Injury Surveillance System), although using different search terms may give more results. See "Archived Data" links on the right of the page.

> 151018762 10/5/15 PUT HAND IN PURSE GRABBED VAPE PIPE BURN FINGER,BLISTER,DX:BURN FINGER
>
> 150750237 7/22/15 IN CAR W/BATTERY OF A VAPORIZER IN HIS PANTS POCKET WHEN IT BEGAN SMOKING & EXPLODED, CAUGHT PANTS ON FIRE, ? FD, DX: BURN THIGH, HANDS
>
> 160211088 12/25/15 INGESTED UNKNOWN AMT. OF LIQUID VAPOR USED IN VAPOR PENS, AT HOME  DAD'S FRIEND THOUGHT CONTAINER WAS EMPTY. DX: INGESTION- LIQUID VAPOR
>
> 150853949 8/17/15 MOM INGESTION UNK AMT VAP LIQUID OF E-CIG, LARGE AMOUNT NOTED ON BED    LIQUID ON HANDS & LEG DX ACCIDENTAL INGESTION TOPICAL EXPOSURE NICOTINE

[Raw data, 2015](https://www.cpsc.gov/Global/Neiss_prod/NEISS-data-2015-updated-APRIL2016.xlsx)

[Query Tool](https://www.cpsc.gov/cgibin/NEISSQuery/home.aspx)